# Why is void* considered unsafe in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, void-pointers

I'm reading [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#unsafe) C++ FAQ site. Where I saw following line.

> - avoid `void*` (keep them inside low-level functions and data structures
>     if you really need them and present type safe interfaces, usually
>     templates, to your users)

Why is `void*` considered unsafe in C++?

Comment: To use `void*` you need at some point to cast it back to whatever type was pointed to originally. If you get that wrong you have undefined behaviour. Put another way `void*` throws away *type safety*.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of type safety?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, i know. C++ is a strictly typecasting language. then whats problem?

Comment: @rsp _"strictly typecasting language"_ What do you mean? Shouldn't it be obvious what's the problem with `void*` then?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please see this link : https://wandbox.org/permlink/DikGnmRJmdUBVlae

Comment: @rsp Sure, and? What makes it _unsafe_ is the fact you need the type cast. If you use the wrong one (e.g. to `double*`), you're lost. It might be hard for a programmer to choose the correct type cast in a more complex scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is void* considered unsafe in C++?

Because `void*` represents a memory address without any type information. The compiler cannot know what data type structures are used what the raw memory contains at that address.

In that case the programmer is in charge to do the deciphering of the memory layout themselves correctly, which is an error prone process, and the programmer need to know exactly what they are doing there.

In that sense as it is said what you've been citing (emphasis mine)

> > - avoid `void*` (keep them inside low-level functions and data structures if you really need them and present ***type safe*** interfaces, usually templates, to your users)

it is about loosing *type safety* with `void*`.

---

To add up about the cite above:

A template in c++ is preferred, because the original type information won't ever get lost as with *generic* c style functions using `void*` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of providing "generic" functions or data structures in C is to use `void*` as the data type, so that any allocated memory could be put into it. This has the unfortunate effect of allowing putting different types of data into the same container. In C++, this is solved by providing "templates", which create type-safe instances of functions and classes/structs at compile time, thus ensuring type correctness.